# NSOpenPanel search field: some found files with allowed type are greyed

Tags: macos, nsopenpanel

On MacOS 10.14 & 10.15, using a NSOpenPanel with an array of allowed file types, the content of the selected directory displays correctly all allowed-type files. But if I use the panel's search field with an allowed extension, some problems arise:

On 10.14, most of the found filenames appear greyed, despite of being selectable and openable.

On 10.15, none of the files are found...

I implemented the delegation `panel:shouldEnableURL:` method as:

```
-(BOOL)panel:(id)sender shouldEnableURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSString *fileExtension = [url pathExtension];
    if ([self.allowedExtensions containsObject:fileExtension]) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I checked wether the correct flag (TRUE/FALSE) is returned, so I don't understand this problem

Comment: Is `allowedFileTypes` set? Are the files found in the Finder on 10.15?

Comment: Yes, it is set. And all the files are found by the Finder, that's very strange...